# Is there a way to group_by with_index in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

So I have this (nicely sorted) array.

And sometimes I need all of the elements from the array. But other times I need all of the even-indexed members together and all of the odd-indexed members together. And then again, sometimes I need it split into three groups with indices 0,3,6 etc. in one group, then 1,4,7 in the next and finally 2,5,8 in the last.

This can be done with `group_by` and taking the modulus of the index. See for yourself:

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/4kzj

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
puts arr.group_by { |x| arr.index(x).not_nil! % 1 } # {0 => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
puts arr.group_by { |x| arr.index(x).not_nil! % 2 } # {0 => ['a', 'c', 'e'], 1 => ['b', 'd']}
puts arr.group_by { |x| arr.index(x).not_nil! % 3 } # {0 => ['a', 'd'], 1 => ['b', 'e'], 2 => ['c']}
```

But that `not_nil!` in there feels like a code-smell / warning that there's a better way.

Can I get the index of the elements without needing to look it up and handle the Nil type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also just do:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
i = 0
puts arr.group_by { |x| i += 1; i % 1 }
i = 0
puts arr.group_by { |x| i += 1; i % 2 }
i = 0
puts arr.group_by { |x| i += 1; i % 3 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides the nilable return type, it's also very inefficient to call `Array#index` for each element. This means a runtime of O(N²).

`#group_by` is used for grouping by value, but you don't need the value for grouping as you just want to group by index. That can be done a lot easier than wrapping around `#group_by` and `#index`

A more efficient solution is to loop over the indices and group the values based on the index:

```
groups = [[] of Char, [] of Char]
arr.each_index do |i|
  groups[i % 2] << arr[i]
end
```

There is no special method for this, but it's fairly simple to implement yourself.

If you don't need all groups, but only one of them, you can also use `Int32#step` to iterate every other index:

```
group = [] of Char
2.step(to: arr.size - 1, by: 3) do |i|
  group << arr[i]
end
```